# How to read user input from a script piped to bash

Tags: bash, pipe, stdin

I want to read user input from inside a bash script `test.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Do you want to continue? (y/n) " yn

case $yn in 
    [yY] ) echo "Doing stuff...";
        echo "Done!";;
    [nN] ) echo "Exiting...";
        exit;;
    * ) echo "Invalid response";;
esac
```

When running the script directly using either `./test.sh` or `bash test.sh` this works fine.

However, I want to run this script (well, a more complicated version of it) from a URL so am calling it like this:

`curl -s https://<myurl>/test.sh | bash -s`

This runs the script but it only displays `Invalid Response`, nothing else (doesnt even print the "Do you want to continue?" message). I understand that this is because the stdout from curl is piped to stdin for bash but how is it possible to read user input in this case?

For completeness, I also get the same behaviour if the script is saved locally and I do:

`bash < test.sh`

Comment: Your script stores the first line of the stdout from the curl command into the variable `yn`. Since this line likely does not contain Y or N, you get the invalid response. You can verify this by doing a `curl -s https://<myurl>/test.sh | head -n 1| tee| bash -s`?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to replace

```
read -p "Do you want to continue? (y/n) " yn
```

with

```
read -p "Do you want to continue? (y/n) " yn </dev/tty
```

to prevent `read` from reading from `stdin` (your pipe).